# How to fix error in code and store data as csv in a for loop?

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, save

I want to create 100 random paths using TrajGenerate (package trajr) and store each trajectory as a separate csv. I've tried the following For loop to do this:

```
for (i in 1:100) {
traj[i]<-TrajGenerate(n=304,random=TRUE,stepLength=8561.488,fps=1)
write.csv(traj[i],file="traj_[i].csv")
}
```

However, this doesn't work as I only get one csv in my directory file - not 100.
How can I make my code work?

Comment: `file="traj_[i].csv"` is just a string and will be the same for each loop. Try: `file = paste0("traj_[", i, "].csv")`. This will generate a different file name for each loop.

Comment: that worked, thanks!